# Parse paragraph and subsequent element with BeautifulSoup with one loop-cycle

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a long list of blog comments which are coded as

```
<p> This is the text <br /> of the comment </p>
<div id="comment_details"> Here the details of the same comment </div>
```

I need to parse comment and details in the same cycle of the loop so to store them orderly.

Yet I am not sure how I should proceed because I can parse them easily in two different loops. Is it elegant and practical to do it in only one?

Please consider the following MWE

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="firstDiv">
     <br></br>
     <p>My first paragraph.<br />But this a second line</p>
     <div id="secondDiv">
          <b>Date1</b>
     </div> 
     <br></br>  
     <p>My second paragraph.</p>
     <div id="secondDiv">
          <b>Date2</b>
     </div> 
     <br></br>
     <p>My third paragraph.</p>
     <div id="secondDiv">
          <b>Date3</b>
     </div>
     <br></br>
     <p>My fourth paragraph.</p>
     <div id="secondDiv">
          <b>Date4</b>
     </div>
     <br></br>
     <p>My fifth paragraph.</p>
     <div id="secondDiv">
          <b>Date5</b>
     </div>
     <br></br>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

for p in soup.find(id="firstDiv").find_all("p"):
        print p.get_text()

for div in soup.find(id="firstDiv").find_all(id="secondDiv"):
        print div.b.get_text()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really wanted the subsequent sibling, that would be easy:

```
for p in soup.find(id="firstDiv").find_all("p"):
    print p.get_text()
    print p.next_sibling.b.get_text()
```

However, the next thing after the `p` is the string `'\n', not the div you want.

The problem is, there is no real structural relationship between the `p` and the `div`; it just so happens that each `p` always has a `div` with a certain `id` as a later sibling, and you want to exploit that. (If you're generating this HTML, obviously fix the structure… but I'll assume you aren't.) So, here are some options.

---

The best is probably:

```
for p in soup.find(id="firstDiv").find_all("p"):
    print p.get_text()
    print p.find_next_sibling(id='secondDiv').b.get_text()
```

---

If you only care about this particular document, and you know that it will always be true that the next sibling after the next sibling is the div you want:

```
print p.get_text()
print p.next_sibling.next_sibling.b.get_text()
```

Or you could rely on the fact that `find_next_sibling()` with no argument, unlike `next_sibling`, skips to the first actual DOM element, so:

```
print p.get_text()
print p.get_next_sibling().b.get_text()
```

---

If you don't want to rely on any of that, but can count on the fact that they're always one-to-one (that is, no chance of any stray `p` elements without a corresponding `secondDiv`), you can just zip the two searches together:

```
fdiv = soup.find(id='firstDiv')
for p, sdiv in zip(fdiv.find_all('p'), fdiv.find_all(id='secondDiv'):
    print p.get_text(), div.b.get_text()
```

---

You could also iterate `p.next_siblings` to find the element you want:

```
for p in soup.find(id='firstDiv').find_all('p'):
    div = next(sib for sib in p.next_siblings if sib.id == 'secondDiv')
    print p.get_text(), div.b.get_text()
```

But ultimately, that's just a more verbose way of writing the first solution, so go back to that one. :)