# Parse multiple paragraph in a single loop-cycle with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am parsing the comment section of a blog. The structure is unfortunately quite irregular.

Here two situations I am facing:

The first comment will be divided in multiple paragraphs

```
 <p>My first paragraph.<br />But this a second line</p>
 <p>And this is a third line</p>
```

while the second only in one paragraph.

I want to parse each comment in a string variable. But executing the following code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="firstDiv">
     <br></br>
     <p>First comment and first line</p>
     <p>First comment and second line</p>
     <div id="secondDiv">
          <b>Date1</b>
     </div> 
     <br></br>  
     <p>Second comment</p>
     <div id="secondDiv">
          <b>Date2</b>
     </div> 
     <br></br>
     </div>
     <br></br>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

for p in soup.find(id="firstDiv").find_all("p"):
    print "Print comment: " + p.get_text()
    print "End of loop"
```

the program will catch the first two paragraph in different instances of the loop, printing

```
Print comment: First comment and first line
End of loop
Print comment: First comment and second line
End of loop
Print comment: Second comment
End of loop
```

How could I proceed to print the first two paragraphs in the same loop?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Also, you should link to [your previous question](What are you asking here that wasn't answered in [your question a couple hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25102651/parse-paragraph-and-subsequent-element-with-beautifulsoup-with-one-loop-cycle)?), which is almost certainly related, and explain how what you're asking is different now.

Comment: @abarnert It's a different question. I need to store the first comment (which is divided in two different paragraphs `<p>`) in a single string. I wondered how I could do it. I thought I could leverage on the fact that in any case the comment, even if in multiple paragraphs, ends when `<div id="secondDiv">`, but I am not sure how to implement that...

Answer (score 0):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
text = [''.join(s.findAll(text=True))for s in soup.findAll('p')]

text = [''.join(s.findAll(text=True))for s in soup.findAll('p')]
print ", ".join(text[:2])
print " ".join(text[2:])

First comment and first line, First comment and second line
Second comment
```

When call `soup.find(id="firstDiv").find_all("p")`  it creates a list as below, so it is logical that iterating over three elements in the list you getting three loops:

```
[<p>First comment and first line</p>, <p>First comment and second line</p>, <p>Second comment</p>]
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think this is what he's asking for. I think he wants to get the first two paragraphs in one iteration, then the third paragraph in another (because they're separated by `div` elements in between), and so on.

Comment: @abarnert, `soup.find(id="firstDiv").find_all("p")` is a list so it is not that the `find` is not finding all on the first iteration, the op is just looping over the elements in the list.

Comment: Your new answer is closer to what I think (and again, I could be wrong…) he's looking for, but it won't actually work, because the second group of `p` nodes aren't children of the `secondDiv`, they're just children of `firstDiv` that happen to come after `secondDiv`.

Comment: @abarnert, I understand that but without using findall and joining I don't see how the OP will get there

Comment: @CptNemo, so you want the first  two paragraphs together and then that last paragraph separately yes?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do here isn't a job for soup, because you're dealing with flat data whose structure isn't reflected in the HTML. So, you want to let the soup take you as far as it can, then switch over to iteration.

The easiest way to get the `p` and `div` children of the parent `div` is to just get all the children. We only want the HTML nodes, not the strings between them, so we can find with no parameters. Like this:

```
def chunkify(parent):
    """yields groups of <p> nodes separated by <div> siblings"""
    chunk = []
    for element in parent.find_all():
        if element.name == 'p':
            chunk.append(element)
        elif element.name == 'div':
            yield chunk
            chunk = []
    if chunk:
        yield chunk

for paras in chunkify(soup.find(id="firstDiv")):
    print "Print comment: " + '\n'.join(p.get_text() for p in paras)
    print "End of loop"
```

The output will be:

```
Print comment: First comment and first line
First comment and second line
End of loop
Print comment: Second comment
End of loop
```

And that's what you want, right?

---

You can write that function much more compactly, and I think more readably if you understand `itertools`… but I wanted to write it in a way that would make more sense to a novice, even if it's clunkier, first. Here's a shorter version:

```
def chunkify(parent):
    """yields groups of <p> nodes separated by <div> siblings"""
    grouped = groupby(parent.find_all(), lambda element: element.name != 'div')
    groups = (g for k, g in grouped if k)
    return ([node for node in g if node.name == 'p'] for g in groups)
```

You can also replace those first two lines with a higher-level function that wraps `groupby`; I `more-itertools` has this, or at least has something close to it:

```
    groups = isplit(parent.find_all(), lambda element: element.name != 'div')
```